# virtualbox - boot screen gives only a black screen with blinking cursor (18.04 i386)

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I tried installing ubuntu 18.04 on vbox..
Everything was fine..

and after restart..
The screen went BLANK! nothing just a blinking cursor..

earlier i tried it with ubuntu 20.04 but still the same error.. black screen

vm info:

```
type: ubuntu 32-bit
video memory: 128mb
ram: 1500mb
no 3d acceleration 
2 CPUs provided
```

my host info:

```
os: Windows 7
arch: x86
vbox version: v5.2.4
```

Comment: You haven't got the minimum hardware requirements ; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements ; you've asked this before (only it was Unity 7; where you have half the minimum screen memory required for that too).  The requirement as mentioned in prior link applied to 17.04 & later; ie. before the 2017-April release and since. 18.04 is the 2018-April release so the minimum wasn't reduced.   128MB is < 256MB minimum requirement & 3D acceleration is required.

Comment: Use a *lighter* flavor, yes Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop is fully supported (unlike *flavors*), however even if you get it *running* it won't be *fast* or *fun* to use in my experience...  I've got boxes used in QA-testing that date from 2004 that I stopped testing Ubuntu Desktop *long ago* because they lack resources (like your box), where as the Ubuntu *flavors* or Ubuntu Server they are *fun* & *fast* as the resource requirements are so much less.

Answer (score -1):

Your system requirement do not meet for ubuntu
. try increasing the RAM. then try Host+R to reboot vm do this 3-4 times then it should boot normally

it fixed for me.

OR you can also use a light flavour such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me)

Comment: Comments posted 8 hours ago are by far better and more complete than this.